# From a combination, get subsets with members containing the same first element, python

Tags: python, combinations

Suppose I have the following list:

```
 ls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I get a combination using

```
 list(itertools.combinations(iterable, 2))  

 >>> [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

What I'd like to do is break this combination into subsets, such that the first member of each tuple in the subset is the same:

```
 subset1: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd')]
 subset2: [('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), 
 subset3: [('c', 'd')]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The first member of the third tuple in `subset2` is `c`, while the other first members are `b`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Shouldn't `subset2` instead be split into two subsets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> ls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> ii=it.groupby( it.combinations(ls, 2), lambda x: x[0] )
>>> for key, iterator in ii:
...     print key, list(iterator)
... 
a [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd')]
b [('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
c [('c', 'd')]
```

If you don't like `lambda`, you could use `operator.itemgetter(0)` instead of `lambda x: x[0]`.

Comment: This answer also has the benefit over the others thus far of not requiring that the list of all combinations actually get created (groupby can process a generator just as well as an instantiated list, but the others process the input sequence multiple times). Would be a much more significant advantage if `ls` were `string.ascii_letters` (52 elements) and they were taken 5 at a time instead of just 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
subset = [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
subsets = [[x for x in subset where x[0] == y] for y in ['a','b','c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[filter(lambda k:k[0]==p,comb) for p in ls]
```

where:

```
ls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

comb = [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

the output is:

```
[[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd')], [('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')], [('c', 'd')], []]
```